# Double Sum Computation Issue

Tags: summation

I'm trying to compute a double sum...

For scalars, it seems to be working fine. Here is an example:

```
 Sum[ρ^(h - 1)/
 Sum[ρ^x, {x, 0, h - 1}], {h, 1, ∞}] /. {λ -> 
 0.5, μ -> 2.0, ρ -> 0.5}
```

But for matrices, similar code does not work.

```
Subscript[I, 2] = IdentityMatrix[2];
e = ({{1, 1}})
p = ({{1, 0}})
B = ( {{μ, -μ}, {0, μ}} )
Q = Transpose[e].p
V = Inverse[B];
EX = p.V.Transpose[e] /. {μ -> 2.0}
A = Subscript[I, 2] + 1/λ B - Q
U = Inverse[A]

Sum[p.MatrixPower[U, h - 1].Transpose[e]/
Sum[p.MatrixPower[U, x].Transpose[e], {x, 0, h - 1}], {h, 
 1, ∞}] /. {λ -> 0.5, μ -> 2.0, ρ -> 0.5}
```

I am unclear what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to do the sum symbolically and then assign values for Lambda etc..? If you could assign them values in the beginning it would be better.

Comment: The question is still ill posed. In the first part there in only a dependency on $\rho$, not on $\lambda$ or $\mu$! The first sum is not a double sum. It is an infinite sum $\sum _{h=1}^{\infty } \frac{(\rho -1) \rho ^{h-1}}{\rho ^h-1}$! If that should be reproduced in the matrix version the complete summands have to be of the first sum form.

Answer (score 0):

Continuation of my comment: I meant have:

```
λ = 0.5; μ = 2.0; ρ = 0.5;
```

The sum value evaluates to

```
{{1.59413}}
```

Also please use i instead of I

=========

## Here is the full code:

```
λ = 0.5; μ = 2.0; ρ = 0.5;

Subscript[i, 2] = IdentityMatrix[2];
e = ({{1, 1}});
p = ({{1, 0}});
B = ({{μ, -μ}, {0, μ}});
Q = Transpose[e].p;
V = Inverse[B];
EX = p.V.Transpose[e] /. {μ -> 2.0};
A = Subscript[i, 2] + 1/λ B - Q;
U = Inverse[A];

N@Sum[p.MatrixPower[U, h - 1].Transpose[e]/
   Sum[p.MatrixPower[U, x].Transpose[e], {x, 0, h - 1}], {h, 
   1, ∞}]

{{1.59413}}
```

Comment: How did you get the sum? I keep on getting an error of some sort...

Comment: My answer looks like this: \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(h = 
   1\), \(\[Infinity]\)]\((7.374511920474766`*^30\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(9.1072613`*^7\), \(1.`\ h\)]\ \
\((\(-0.5914103126634984`\)\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(0.1524029491994481`\), \(\(-1\) + h\)] + 
     1.5914103126634984`\ 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(0.4100970508005519`\), \(\(-1\) + h\)])\))\)\)...